# Sum iteratively in sql based on what value next row has?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, cumulative-sum, gaps-and-islands

I want to aggregate a transaction table in a way that it sums checking a variable in next row and sums if condition is met, otherwise breaks and start summing again creating a new row. This might be confusing, so adding example below -
**What I have -**

| ID | date | type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1/1/2023 | incoming | 10 |
| a | 2/1/2023 | incoming | 10 |
| a | 3/1/2023 | incoming | 10 |
| a | 4/1/2023 | incoming | 10 |
| a | 5/1/2023 | outgoing | 20 |
| a | 6/1/2023 | outgoing | 10 |
| a | 7/1/2023 | incoming | 10 |
| a | 8/1/2023 | incoming | 10 |
| a | 9/1/2023 | outgoing | 30 |
| a | 10/1/2023 | incoming | 10 |

**Summary Output I want -**

| ID | type | min_date | max_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | incoming | 1/1/2023 | 4/1/2023 | 40 |
| a | outgoing | 5/1/2023 | 6/1/2023 | 30 |
| a | incoming | 7/1/2023 | 8/1/2023 | 20 |
| a | outgoing | 9/1/2023 | 9/1/2023 | 30 |
| a | incoming | 10/1/2023 | 10/1/2023 | 10 |

Basically keep summing until the next row has same transaction type (after sorting on date), if it changes create a new row and repeat same process.
Thanks!

I tried approaches like using window function (dense_rank) and sum() over (partition by) but not getting the output I am looking for.

Comment: What DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL) are you using?

Comment: Amazon Redshift

Comment: Redshift is PostgreSQL. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_commands.html#:~:text=The%20SQL%20language%20consists%20of,Redshift%20is%20based%20on%20PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using window functions is the correct approach, you need to identify when the type changes (one way is to use `Lag` or `Lead`) and then assign grouping to each set, see if the following gives your expected results:

```
with d as (
  select *, 
    case when lag(type) over(partition by id order by date) = type then 0 else 1 end diff
  from t
), grp as (
  select *, Sum(diff) over(partition by id order by date) grp
  from d
)
select Id, Type, 
  Min(date) Min_Date, 
  Max(Date) Max_Date, 
  Sum(Amount) Amount
from grp
group by Id, Type, grp
order by Min_Date;
```

See this [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5OumFueL)

Comment: Thanks @Stu, works perfectly for my use case.